# Displaying Dropzone.js based on select value from a dropdown

Tags: jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I'm trying to display Dropzone.js based on a select option in my dropdown, and not on load. But it does not work for me.

I'm trying to fiddle with the init() function, but my method may be wrong.

Basically, this would be my dropdown field.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
   <!-- Select2 (.js-select2 class is initialized in App() -> uiHelperSelect2()) -->
   <!-- For more info and examples you can check out https://github.com/select2/select2 -->
      <div class="form-material">
      <select class="js-select2 form-control" id="product-category" name="product-category" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
          <option></option><!-- Required for data-placeholder attribute to work with Select2 plugin -->
          <option value="1">PDF</option>
          <option value="2">Image</option>
          <option value="3">Youtube Link</option>
      </select>
      <label for="example2-select2">Category</label>
      </div>
   </div></div>
```

And this is my dropzone init.

```
init: function() {
var myDropzone = this;
```

So how do I make it such that the dropzone only shows when the selected value for product-category is 2. For images only. and when i switch back to 1 or 3, pdf and youtube, the dropzone does not show.

Any advice or help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What errors you get in console?

Comment: @Saromase no errors, but the dropzone part, I want it hidden unless i select value = 2.